# Unique Key on two table

Tags: mysql

is it possible to make two tables have a unique key like if my first table has the unique key and the second table cannot have the same text as the first table, it is possible to make that?

### --
-- Table structure for table `admin`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `admin`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
`ID` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`PhoneNumber` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`UniqueCode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `UniqueCode` (`UniqueCode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `admin`

INSERT INTO `admin` (`ID`, `Name`, `Password`, `Email`, `PhoneNumber`, `UniqueCode`) VALUES
('AA11', 'Admin Low', '827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b', 'AA11@gmail.com', '6012346778', 'Lmao'),
('AA12', 'Admin Tyler', '827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b', 'AA11@gmail.com', '6033556778', 'Rofl');

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `lecturer`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `lecturer`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lecturer` (
`ID` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`PhoneNumber` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`UniqueCode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `UniqueCode` (`UniqueCode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `lecturer`

INSERT INTO `lecturer` (`ID`, `Name`, `Password`, `Email`, `PhoneNumber`, `UniqueCode`) VALUES
('AL11', 'Cat Eat my son', '827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b', 'AL11@gmail.com', '6012342222', 'Meow'),
('AL12', 'Dog Eat my son', '827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b', 'AL12@gmail.com', '6033345678', 'Woof');

Comment: Consider having 1 table with a role column(s)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check before inserting data by useng "EXIST".
The EXISTS operator is used to test for the existence of any record in a subquery.
The EXISTS operator returns TRUE if the subquery returns one or more records.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE condition);
```

Comment: Because i am using this as a reset password function, I want to have different table to have unique key so it doesn't crash with the function I made

Comment: is it possible to have 2 tables with the unique key?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-multiple-tables-have-the-same-primary-key